# Linkedlist eliminar elemento por pos

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de pasar un test de la facultad en donde me piden eliminar un elemento de la linkedlist con una pos que me pasan como parametro ellos. El tema es que no entiendo porque el codigo me tira "Cannot read property "next" of null en esta linea "current = current.next"

```
List.prototype.remove = function(pos){
 
if(pos>this.size) return false 
if(pos<0) return false 

var current = this.head
var previous;
var count = 0;

if(pos === 0){
  this.head = current.next
} else {
   while(count < pos) {
     count++;
     previous = this.head;
     current = current.next
   }
   previous.next = this.head.next
  }
  this.size--
};
```

Por lo que veo cuando debugeo es que el primer this.head es 0

Comment: Saludos! como la pregunta es un ejercicio de clases no responderé directamente; pero puedes hacerte esta pregunta ¿Qué pasa en tu código si la lista está vacía y tratas de eliminar el que se encuentra en la posición 2?

Comment: Por cierto: en la descripción te faltó mostrar un ejemplo del código que estás ejecutando. Por ejemplo `var prueba = new List(): prueba.remove(2);`

Comment: Hola, me fije y la lista tiene solo dos valores (1,2) pero sigo sin entender porque a next lo toma como null si deberia ser dos

Comment: ¿Cuál es la definición de `List`? no es un tipo u objeto estándar de Javascript (en Javascript no hay listas vinculadas). Si estás usando una librería externa debes indicarlo, porque el problema no está en el código anterior, sino en como se supone que funciona List: al crear un objeto List y agregar ítems, la propiedad `head` debería apuntar automáticamente al primero, y la propiedad `next` de cada ítem debe apuntar al siguiente.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedList.prototype.remove = function(){

```
if(!this.head) return null;

if(this.head.next === null){
  let arg = this.head.arg;
  this.head = null;
  return arg;
}

let current = this.head;
while(current.next.next){
  current = current.next;
}

let arg = current.next.arg;
current.next = null;
return arg;
```

}

de esta manera tambien te podria fucionar

Comment: Lee [answer]: explica qué hace este código, y en qué resuelve la duda al OP (autor de la pregunta).